# How to set title fontsize in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Is there a simple way to change the fontsize of only (i.e., everything else should remain unchanged) the title in Plots.jl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `titlefontsize` keyword argument. As documented: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_subplot/#

Answer (score 0):

Might also be interesting how to define a font and size at the same time, for both title and axis:

```
plot(title = "Awesome Title",
    titlefont = font(12,"Computer Modern"),
    guidefont = font(9,"Computer Modern")
 )
```